# Pidgin sort buddy group alphabetically

Tags: plugins, pidgin

I was trying to make Pidgin interface look similar to Windows Live Messenger. Is there any Pidgin plugin can sort buddy group alphabetically without manually sort?

Another question - is there any plugin can put all offline buddies in one group like WLM does?

Comment: I find it more convenient to just *hide* offline buddies.

Answer (score 0):

The only way at the moment to sort groups is to create them they way the want to appear in the list. The last created group appears on the top.

Answer (score -1):

The alphabetical sort is done simply by going into the Buddies menu >> Sort >> Aphabetical.

Comment: that's sort buddy, I need sort group name.